# How to read JSON file in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am working on a project where i have to read the product and display it on my HTML page 
here is my Controller

```
  app.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope,srvShareCart ,srvShareData,srvAddtoCart,$http) {
      $scope.product=[];
    $scope.One=function(){
     //alert($scope.ids);
       $scope.ids= srvAddtoCart.getData();
       for (var i=0; i<$scope.ids.length; i++){
      $http.get("http://www.ilexsquare.com/JwelTech/wordpress/api.php?function=GetProduct&id="+$scope.ids[i])
        .then(function (response) {

            srvShareCart.addData(response.data);
        });

        $scope.cart = srvShareCart.getData();
        console.log($scope.cart);

     }

    }
```

and here is My HTML page

```
<div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
    <ul> <li class=oxy-list__item  ng-repeat="d in cart">{{d.title}}</li></ul></div>
```

here is a working API

this the Example API [link](http://www.ilexsquare.com/JwelTech/wordpress/api.php?function=GetProduct&id=1169)

it's giving me an error in **response.data** which is coming as undefined.what is the issue in it ?
I am getting the output but it's not in a form of array.. how do i Add those products in array. i have tried `$scope.carts.push($scope.products);` but its not storing as an array

Comment: Have you debugged response? What is returned in response?

Comment: `Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data` this is the error

Comment: Ok, what is in `$scope.ids[i]` and what did you get returned if you call `http://www.ilexsquare.com/JwelTech/wordpress/api.php?function=GetProduct&id="+$scope.ids[i]` directly in your browser replaced by the id which was in `$scope.ids[i]`.

Comment: this the Example API [link](http://www.ilexsquare.com/JwelTech/wordpress/api.php?function=GetProduct&id=1169)

Comment: This works for me. But are you sure, that you have the correct id within `$scope.ids[i]`. I mean have you checked this?

Comment: Yes, I am getting the response from the server also which is displaying the right content

Comment: I am getting the output but it's not in a form of array.. how do i Add those products in array. i have tried `$scope.carts.push($scope.products);` but its not storing as an array

Comment: You can consider to accept any one answer,

Answer (score 2):

The response content type sent from the API is `plain text` instead of `application/json`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try like this.

```
         $http.get({
            url: "http://www.ilexsquare.com/JwelTech/wordpress/api.php?function=GetProduct&id="+$scope.ids[i],
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                srvShareCart.addData(response.data);
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.d);
            }
        });
```